# Can I specify any method as the callback when constructing a Scrapy Request object?

Tags: python, callback, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create a request and have been previously passing a function in my spider class as the callback. However, I've since moved that function to an Item subclass, because I'd like to have different types of Items and the callback may be different for each sort of item (e.g. at the moment I'm going to raise DropItem if the content type isn't as expected, and have a different set of valid MIME types for each type of Item). So, what I was wondering was can I pass a function from my Item subclass as the callback parameter? Basically like so:

```
item = MyCustomItem()  # Extends scrapy.item.Item
# bunch of code here...
req = Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), method="HEAD", callback=item.parse_resource_metadata)
```

At the moment `item.parse_resource_metadata` isn't getting called. Printing `req.callback` gives

```
<bound method ZipResource.parse_resource_metadata of {(correct data for this Item object}>
```

so it at least constructs the request as I had hoped it would.

[edit] Mea culpa, the callback wasn't called because the start page wasn't being crawled (I had to override `parse_start_url()`. But turns out I was doing things wrong, so good thing I asked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, it is doable since `callback` is just a callable that has a `response` as it's argument.

Though, `Item`s are just containers of the fields, they are for storing data, you *should not put logic there*.

Better create a method in the spider and [pass the `item` instance inside `meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta):

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    item = MyCustomItem()
    ...
    yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), 
                  method="HEAD", 
                  meta={'item': item},
                  callback=self.my_callback)

def my_callback(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    ...
```

---

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve, but you might also take a closer look at [`Item Loaders`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#module-scrapy.contrib.loader) and [`Input and Output Processors`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise they were just supposed to be containers. I've got a UrlResource class that extends Item. I'll avoid having functions in my Item subclasses, but is it ok for an Item subclass to have class attributes? [edit] (other than Fields)

Comment: @false_azure thank you, could you please show the `UrlResource` implementation?

Comment: I can post the code if it's helpful, but it's just an Item subclass with some Fields (now that I've taken the callback function out).

Comment: @false_azure okay, in theory, it should be smth like this: `spider` has all of the logic for extracting the data from the response, instantiating items with data, calling item loaders etc. All of the logic for prettifying and editing the data should be inside the item loaders and input and output processors. Then, pipelines are for storing the items in the database. This is how I've structured it. I've always had items as simple classes based on `Item` containing `Fields`. See also http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/architecture.html. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I should have read into the architecture.